# How do calculate square root of Big Decimal more efficiently than Newton Raphson?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I want to calculate square root of a big decimal in my application. Please don't suggest some third party utilities since i can't go in the loop of licencing.
I have been  using Newton-Raphson Method but since it uses pow and divide operation heavily. I can see it slowing down my application in profiler. Can you guys suggest me some good implementation for this?
Either there can be some different algorithm than Newton-Raphson or may be if not then some faster implementation of it using bitwise operation.

Comment: The quadratic convergence of the newton method is hard to beat. Just make sure, you start with a good initial estimate of the square root. The square root calculated with double precision may be a good start.

Comment: @Naman For what are using pow function ?

Comment: @VikramBhat I was using this implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649703/square-root-of-bigdecimal-in-java

Comment: @Naman do really need big decimal because big decimal is usually slower to primitive data types

Comment: @Naman Prevent the recursive implementation as given in the answer but use iterative one because it takes a lot of stack space and slows down the speed.

Comment: @Naman Use multiply instead of Pow(2)

Comment: Newton Raphson for square roots is equivalent to the divide and average method, which may be simpler to implement (and involves one division, one add, and then one division by two).

Comment: To compute square roots rapidly, one usually computes via the reciprocal square root, for which division-free iterations are readily available. Iterative schemes with cubic and higher convergence are well known (cubic is usually sufficient for double precision computation), see for example: http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/inverse

Comment: @njuffa This sounds interesting. I'll check the link, also if you can provide some more insight for implementation that would be great.

Comment: @Naman: Sorry, I am not familiar with Java or BigDecimal. You may want to re-arrange the arithmetic for the iterations in a manner most suitable for the native API. Except for zero and infinity, sqrt(x) = x * rsqrt(x).

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary search to find square root.
Something like that:

```
BigDecimal sqrt(BigDecimal a){
    BigDecimal left = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal right = a;

    for (int i = 0; i < BINARY_SEARCH_ITER_COUNT; ++i) {
        BigDecimal middle = left.add(right).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2));

        if (middle.multiply(middle).compareTo(a) < 0) {
            left = middle;
        } else {
            right = middle;
        }
    }

    return left.add(right).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2));
}
```

You can tune the number of iterations to match your precision and exectuion time requrements. But I don't know how this works in comparison with Newton-Raphson.

Comment: Binary search is a slower algorithm than Newton-Raphson. Binary search exhibits linear convergence, whereas Newton-Raphson has quadratic convergence.

Comment: Agree with @ChrisTaylor...Binary search through Newton-Raphson is very much slower