# Is there any wrong with this BigDecimal calculation?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am new to BigDecimal.
I tried some math calculations using Java code. When I try the same calculations using Google calculator it gives me a slightly different results. Which one is the most accurate?. If Google calculator is more accurate, then how to improve java code to match it?.

On Google calculator:

134.23576185216913 - (134.23576185216913 × √(1 - (200000000^2 ÷ 299800000^2))) = **34.2357618522**

On Java:

```
      BigDecimal t1 = new BigDecimal(134.23576185216913);
      BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1);
      BigDecimal speed = new BigDecimal(200000000).pow(2);
      BigDecimal lightsSpeed = new BigDecimal(299800000).pow(2);

      MathContext mc = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
      System.out.println(t1.subtract((t1.multiply(SquareRoot.bigSqrt(one.subtract(speed.divide(lightsSpeed,mc)))))));
```

The method of bigSqrt is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306433/1576401)

The result is:

run:
**34.683856455950090090043113321827989040137639817587194953722595479211000578082422197809603912048352550091209304856567024386365147605287692511973841869226169664820176852861655846233912503305984796190828666994508412096618025960010635831985100961879858807909056676663493607611105279976694118991120829708264297254294821755138400476425886154174804687500**
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: It may be helpful to reduce this down to the smallest portion which still shows the difference.  For example, I imagine the loss isn't in the subtraction, you can probably remove that piece and still see the difference.  The simplest case is always easiest to debug.

Comment: Eventhough you use a `BidDecimal`, you construct it with a `double` literal: `134.23576185216913`. Precision changes begin right there. where do you get `134.23576185216913` from? Can this be preresented as a fraction? That may yeild better results.

Comment: And where is the `SquareRoot` class from?

Comment: @Nivas I wrote an Empty class `SquareRoot` to add `bigSqrt` method to it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17306433/1576401)

Answer (score 7):

This is your issue:

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

your are rounding the division to 2 decimal places. Use `MathContext mc = new MathContext(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);` instead (for example) and you should get something closer to the expected result.

You can see the difference with:

```
System.out.println(speed.divide(lightsSpeed,new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
System.out.println(speed.divide(lightsSpeed,new MathContext(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
```

which prints:

> 0.45
>   0.445037630156818

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear to me what is happening mathematically and in terms of data structures. To my understanding, BigDecimal can represent only certain rational numbers, by no means arbitrary square roots. The linked method in `SquareRoot` would return some approximation of the actual square root, which also seems to be the case from a superficial inspection of the code.