# K nearest neighbour in a 2d plane

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, priority-queue

The Question statement is as follows:

> Find the K closest points to the origin in a 2D plane, given an array
>   containing N points.The output must be in non decreasing order.

**Solution**: I have solved this using comparator and priority queue and my code looks like below:

```
class Point {
    double x;
    double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class KClosestPoints {
    public Point[] getKNearestPoints(Point[] points, int k) {
        if (k == 0 || points.length == 0) {
            return new Point[0];
        }
        Point[] rValue = new Point[k];
        int index = k - 1;
        if (points.length < k) {
            index = points.length - 1;
        }
        final Point org = new Point(0, 0);
        PriorityQueue<Point> pq = new PriorityQueue<Point>(k,
                new Comparator<Point>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
                    Double d2 = getDistance(o2, org);
                    Double d1 = getDistance(o1, org);
                    if (d2 > d1) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (d2 < d1) {
                        return -1;
                    } else
                        return 0;
                }
                });
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            pq.offer(points[i]);
            if (pq.size() > k) {
                pq.poll();
            }
        }
        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            rValue[index] = pq.poll();
            index--;
        }
        return rValue;
    }

    private static double getDistance(Point a, Point b) {
        return Math.sqrt(((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x))
                + ((a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y)));
    }
```

My Code works for all test cases i have used except this:

```
test6[0] = new Point(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
test6[1] = new Point(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE);
test6[2] = new Point(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
getKNearestPoints(test6, 2);
```

The answer should be test6[0] and test6[1] whereas this code gives answer as test6[0] and test6[2]. Help me in finding the issue.

**EDIT**: Later i have noticed it is giving wrong answer in all the test cases with k = 2 when the points are are positive and negative and one such test case is mentioned above

Comment: Well, what is `Double.MIN_VALUE - Double.MIN_VALUE` in Java? Incidentally, is there a reason why you're using a priority queue for this, rather than just sorting the points by distance to the origin and returning the first `k` of them?

Comment: I can do without priority queue . Then i have to calculate the distance from the origin for every point and then sort the distances and take first k distances. The distances can be mapped with the points using hashmap. I was just thinking of saving the memory and not taking hashmap. The complexity in both the scenarios will be O(n logn)

Comment: I figured out the solution using treeMap though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue you are asking, there is a problem calculating the distance:

```
Point # 0 = (0, 0)
Point # 1 = (Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE) -> (4.9E-324, 1.7E308)
Point # 2 = (Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE) -> (4.9E-324, 4.9E-324)
Point # 3 = (Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE) -> (1.7E308, 1.7E308)
```

**Note:** `Double.MIN_VALUE` is a positive number.

Now the euclidean distance `d = Math.sqrt(((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x)) + ((a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y)));` return `Infinity` when calculating distance between `Point # 0` and `Point # 1`, and between `Point # 0` and `Point # 3`, because:

**Point # 1**

```
(a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) = (1.7E308 - 0) * (1.7E308 - 0) = 1.7E308 * 1.7E308 = Infinity
Math.sqrt(Infinity + Infinity) = Infinity;
```

After getting the distance of `Point # 1` and `Point # 0` (`Infinity`), and then comparing it with the distance of `Point # 3` and `Point # 0` (Also `Infinity`) then `Infinity = Infinity` is `true`, hence the `Comparator` says "Both Points are equal", and the `PriorityQueue` don't order as you wish.

For the operation with `Double.MAX_VALUE` you must not use `Double`, instead use `BigDecimal`:

```
private BigDecimal getDistance(Point a, Point b) {
    BigDecimal dx = BigDecimal.valueOf(a.x - b.x);
    BigDecimal dy = BigDecimal.valueOf(a.y - b.y);
    BigDecimal distance = dx.pow(2).add(dy.pow(2));
    return distance;
}
```

Why are we not calculating the real distance with square root? Because:

- BigDecimal class doesn't has such method (if you which [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649703/square-root-of-bigdecimal-in-java) you can).
- Because if `a > b` then `sqrt(a) > sqrt(b)`, its proportional, so it's enough get the value without apply square root function.

Taking advantage of `BigDecimal`, it implements its own `Comparator` so we use it in the `compareTo` method of the `Comparator` defined:

```
@Override
public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
    BigDecimal d1 = getDistance(o1);
    BigDecimal d2 = getDistance(o2);
    return d1.compareTo(d2);
}
```