# How do I store a irrational BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How do I store a big irrational number like pi or `7^(1/2)`? Preferably I should be able to store a large number of digits (1000+) but not necessary.

Comment: You cannot store an irrational number precisely as a `BigDecimal`. Irrationals do not have a finite decimal representation. You can store an approximation of one. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried MathContext then .round()

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post [the code you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe what problem you had with it.

Comment: Is the question "how to compute a square root or pi to a high precision?" Storing such a number is no different from storing any other number. See for example here for how to compute a square root https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649703/318758

Answer (score 3):

You can not store an irrational number, because its endless. Beside that you can store a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) with a large, but limited number of digits as plain String value. To set the precision of your number you can use [`BigDecimal.setScale()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-). This takes the number of digits and a [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

Here is an example:

```
BigDecimal irrational = ...
BigDecimal result = irrational.setScale(1000, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("test.txt"), result.toPlainString());
```

I would recommend using [`BigDecimal.toPlainString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) instead of [`BigDecimal.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()).

From the docs:

> **`toPlainString()`:** Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.
>
> **`toString()`:** Returns the string representation of this BigDecimal, using scientific notation if an exponent is needed.

Create a new `BigDecimal` from the file you can just pass the String value to the constructor:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("test.txt")));
```

You also can use this to store the number in a database, or wherever you want. Just store it as String value.

Comment: Rounding makes the number rational.

Comment: @Makoto Of course it does, as I wrote in my post: _Of course only a limited number of digits._ You can not store an endless number. But you can set the precision.

Comment: You may wish to rephrase your opening sentence then.  I was given the impression that I could store an irrational number in a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, thanks for that hint. This was not quite clear at the beginning. I updated my post. Hope it is more clear now.