# Relational Operation on two BigIntegers in Java

Tags: java, biginteger, binary-search, comparison-operators

While trying to compute the **square root** of a **BigInteger** using **BINARY SEARCH** method,I was stuck in between as to how to comapre **two BigIntegers** for satisfying comparison operation.
Like, I wanted to check for **equality**,**greater than or lesser than** conditions between two BigInteger variables.

Here is the **wrong piece of code** with rough idea of as to what I want to perform.Any efforts to resolve the issue would be appreciated.

```
public static BigInteger squareroot(BigInteger bi){
    //BigInteger bkl;
    BigInteger low,high,mid;
low=ONE;
high=bi.add(ZERO);
while(low<=high)
{
    mid =(low.add(high)).divide(new BigInteger("2"));
    if(mid.multiply(mid).equals(bi))
        return mid;
    if(mid.multiply(mid) > bi)
        high = mid -1 ;
    else
        low = mid + 1;
}
return mid;
}
```

Comment: Binary search for square root? How does that work?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it performs a binary search with high being the square and low being 0, returning when the binary search finds the integer that is the square root.

Comment: @Human I don't see an array (contiguous or otherwise) in OP's post. Also, what if I pass in `10`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I stated it incorrectly, it starts with the high number being the square + 1 and the low being 0. It converges on the square root as a binary search would when searching for an integer in an array.

Comment: You can just get the rough estimate of getting square root of 10 as 3 approximately when you will run this piece of code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the Square Root of a Java BigInteger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407839/how-can-i-find-the-square-root-of-a-java-biginteger)

Comment: @Elliott Frisch-Your comment has helped me a bit,one good reference can be attributed to http://faruk.akgul.org/blog/javas-missing-algorithm-biginteger-sqrt/

Comment: But,how can I get rid of it in my way of coding!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigInteger`s are `Object`s so you cannot compare their contents with relational operators such as `>`, and `==` won't compare contents; it will compare object references.

However, `BigInteger` does implement `Comparable<BigInteger>`, so call [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo-java.math.BigInteger-) instead.

- For equality, use `left.compareTo(right) == 0`.
- For less than, use `left.compareTo(right) < 0`.
- For greater than, use `left.compareTo(right) > 0`.

Comment: But this is not my question.What will I receive after performing this??? I want to compare two BigIntegers for the greater than or lesser than relation. How will I use this Comparable interface to help me achieve this?

Comment: Calling `compareTo` will certainly help you.  You will be able to compare the values of two `BigInteger`s by calling `compareTo`.  You "use" `Comparable` by calling `compareTo` which is defined by `Comparable`.  The `compareTo` method must be defined because `BigInteger` declares that it implements Comparable.

Comment: While you are always welcome to answer your own question, I don't see what the repetition will gain.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `BigInteger` class correctly:

1. You can replace `high = bi.add(ZERO)` with a simple `high = bi`.
2. The comparison `low <= high` will not compile for `BigInteger` operands.
3. The comparison `mid.multiply(mid) > bi` will not compile for `BigInteger` operands.
4. The arithmetic operations `mid-1` and `mid+1` will not compile for a `BigInteger` operand.
5. Using `divide(new BigInteger("2"))` is not very efficient; use `shiftRight(1)` instead.

**Try this method instead:**

```
public static BigInteger squareroot(BigInteger bi)
{
    BigInteger low  = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger high = bi;
    while (true)
    {
        BigInteger mid0 = low.add(high).shiftRight(1);
        BigInteger mid1 = mid0.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger square0 = mid0.multiply(mid0);
        BigInteger square1 = mid1.multiply(mid1);
        if (square0.compareTo(bi) > 0)
            high = mid0;
        else if (square1.compareTo(bi) <= 0)
            low = mid1;
        else
            return mid0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @shekhar: Well, you've changed the code in your question, so I'm gonna remove this answer in a few minutes...

Comment: My purpose will not be solved if I will assign high=bi. Please correctify it!

Comment: @shekhar: You are wrong. `high=bi.add(ZERO)` in your code is equivalent to `high=bi` in my code. In addition to that, you have several errors in your code: 1. `while(low<=high)`. 2. `if(mid.multiply(mid) > bi)`. And finally, your use of `divide(new BigInteger("2")` is not very efficient, and you can improve it by replacing it with `shiftRight(1)`.

Comment: So,you should have probably read the question in a hurried state.I had already mentioned that I am presenting my wrong code,only to give a fair idea as to what I wanted to achieve. And,moreover,your take over `high=bi`  is wrong as in this program,there is no need to reference to bi's address,rather,it was only intended to provide an instantiation in the beginning!

Comment: @shekhar: I think that your perception of Java is wrong! When you instantiate `high=bi`, it does not mean that `bi` changes whenever `high` changes. Creating a new instance with `high=bi.add(ZERO)` has no effect different than `high=bi` (except for the duplicate instance, so if anything, it makes the performance of your code worse)!

Comment: -No,no,man,I agree with you.But,I am telling that there is no need to reference to an object.Rather,you should have better provided a numeric constant instantiation to the new variable.There is no loss in creating new instance(duplicate,in your view) for achieving the perfection...

Comment: @shekhar: Look inside the loop, and you'll see that `high` is changed to reference a different variable (namely, `mid0`), so there is no reason why it shouldn't reference `bi` before entering the loop.

Comment: -See,in Java, objects are manipulated through reference variables, and there is no operator for copying an object—the assignment operator duplicates the reference, not the object. The clone() method provides this missing functionality.

Comment: @shekhar: You still haven't answer to me (and to yourself), why on earth you are using `high = bi.add(ZERO)`!!!

Comment: -I think you need to strengthen your concepts in Java,you might be missing some important links,or getting confused over time.Check this-->>http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~turner/courses/cs428/current/webct/content/java/jasg.html

Comment: -because I want to use bi somewhere else also,but,if assigned `high=bi`,it will not serve my purpose.
See,in this way high will not be referring to the same point as bi.If I come to change bi somewhere, this attribute high will also reference to the same changed location. I hope you will put something valuable now for me as well as for yourself now!!!

Comment: @shekhar: You **do not** need to create a duplicate instance for `bi`, because you are **not** changing the internal properties of the instance which is referenced by `high`. I have not been able to convince you of that, so I'm not gonna try any further. Please note the additional performance issue, subjected to the use of `divide` instead of `shiftRight` (although the internal implementation of the `BigInteger` class might be handling that efficiently; you can't be sure, so you might as well use `shiftRight` just in order to "stay on the safe side"). Good luck :)

Comment: -That I agree and appreciate that you pointed. Sorry for acknowledging it late.