# What does the ">>" symbol mean in Java?

Tags: java

I see a line in some code I'm looking at and it says (12 >> 1) - 1). I print that value out and it comes out as a 5. If I change the 12 to 5, it comes out as a 1.

What is the ">>" symbol doing exactly?

Comment: yeah I just saw that when I wrote 12 out in binary. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Second link on A Famous Web Search Engine for "java >> operator": [The official Java operators tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: @fge No, it's a right shift

Comment: @pathfinderelite uh, yeah, brain fart

Answer (score 37, accepted):

12 is `1100` in binary. A right shift (>> is the bitwise right shift operator) by one bit produces

```
1100 -> 0110
```

which comes out to be 6.

Thus we have that,

```
6 - 1 = 5
```

Answer (score 58):

`>>` is the signed right shift operator. It shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand.

When you shift right two bits, you drop the two least significant bits.

Let’s say, `x = 00111011`

So when you do, `x >> 2`, it results in `x = 00001110`

This is essentially the same thing as dividing a value by 4 or by 2 two times while dropping the fractional part.

So, below code will result in `4`:

```
byte val = 100;
val = (byte) (val >> 2);
System.out.println(val);
```

**Explaining your example:**

- The binary representation of 12 is: 1100
- 12 >> 1 is equivalent to 0110 which is 6 in decimal
- so (12 >> 1) - 1) is equivalent to 6-1 that is 5

Comment: perhaps you meant result will be 25? 100 / 4 != 4;)

Answer (score 4):

See [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

> The Java programming language also provides operators that perform
>   bitwise and bit shift operations on integral types.  The signed left
>   shift operator `<<` shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed
>   right shift operator `>>` shifts a bit  pattern to the right. The bit
>   pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions
>   to shift by the right-hand operand.  The unsigned right shift operator
>   `>>>` shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost
>   position after `>>` depends on sign extension.

```
(12 >> 1) - 1)
```

`>>` shifts binary `12(1100)` 1 times to the right.
`12 >> 1 == 6(110)`

`6 - 1 == 5`

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit-shift operator. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 2):

`>>` performs arithmetic right shift.

For example:

```
12 >> 1 = 6
-12 >> 1 = -6
```

Answer (score 1):

Binary right shift operator. The left operand's value is moved right by the number of bits specified by the right operand. For example, A >> 2 will give 15 which is 1111 in binary.

More information: *[Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)*