# Converting Decimal value to Binary in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Here is my problem. In the following code, I have a `void` type method, but inside this method, I can still find a `return`.

Also, in the recursion call, I can find this `>>` operator.

So there are my questions :

- Why using a return in a void function ?
- Whats `number >> 1` does it mean ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Code {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Decimal value here : ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        printBinaryform(num);
        System.out.println();
    }
    private static void printBinaryform(int number) {
        int remainder;
        if (number <= 1) {
            System.out.print(number);
            return; // KICK OUT OF THE RECURSION
        }
        remainder = number % 2;
        printBinaryform(number >> 1);
        System.out.print(remainder);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return a value, or expect anything to be returned from the recursive call, so what's the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i don't get if (number <= 1) {
            System.out.print(number);
            return;
but not returning any value ?
and here printBinaryform(number >> 1);
what does ">>" do?

Comment: Of course it's not returning any value, *it's a void function*.  And see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html. SO isn't a tutorial service, I'd recommend finding a structured tutorial to run you through the basics of the language.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ohh, ok Thanks Bro :)

Comment: As usual in these questions, there is no decimal here at all, apart from what the user enters. `Scanner.nextInt()` already does the decimal to binary conversion. What you're doing after that is anybody's guess. Unclear what you're asking,

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `return;` is used to leave the function. In an `String` function, we would have had the `return` keyword, follow by a String value, but in a void function return is just follow by nothing.

The `>>`operator is called a right shift. It is used for the bit shift.
But this question already have an answer here :

[What does “>>” mean in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30004496/7613158)

> 12 is `1100` in binary. A right shift (>> is the bitwise right shift operator) by one bit produces
>
> `1100` -> `0110`
>
> which comes out to be 6.
>
> Thus we have that,
>
> 6 - 1 = 5