# Count Letter recursive method

Tags: java, stack-overflow

So the program has to count letters of a string. I am not allowed to use loops except of recursive ones.

The method has to look like this:

```java
static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount)
```

**Input:**

> abcbabcba (String) and b (char)

**Output:**

> 4

That's what my Code looks like so far ( I get Stackoverflow ) :

```java
static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
 int i = 0;
 int erg = 0;
 if (text.length() != 0) {
   if (i != text.length()) {
     if (text.charAt(i) == characterToCount) {
       i++;
       erg++;
       numberOf(text, characterToCount);
     } else {
       i++;
       numberOf(text, characterToCount);
     }
   } else {
     return erg;
   }
 }

 return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm only allowed to use `String.charAt` and `String.length`

Comment: Imho, unless you permit other methods to be used (including helper methods) or change the signature, this is not possible without exploiting the nature of the character passed (as I did in my example).  You need to fully explain what is and is not permitted to accomplish this?

Comment: The original task is on German... I'm on my Cyber Security studies.
These are the conditions:

*1* The result must be calculated recursively, so you are not allowed to use loops.
You may go through create additional own auxiliary methods for the calculation, but these are also not allowed to include loops.
*2* You can only use the following two methods from the String class: length and charAt.
Further string functions are not permitted!

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Well, if you're allowed to use helper methods that makes the solution very easy.  But since someone else already posted that as a solution I will not be updating my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I got my solution.
It's maybe not that well but it works. Thanks for your help :)

```
public class CountLetters {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    print("Bitte geben Sie den Text ein: ");
    String text = readString();
    text = toLowerCase(text, 0);
    print("Bitte geben Sie ein Zeichen ein: ");
    String zeich = readString();
    zeich = toLowerCase(zeich, 0);
    if (zeich.length() > 1) {
        throw new PR1Exception("Bitte nur einen Buchstaben eingeben. ");
    }
    char zeichen = zeich.charAt(0);

    if (zeichen > 0 && zeichen < 65 && zeichen > 90 && zeichen < 97 && zeichen > 123) {
        throw new PR1Exception("Bitte nur Buchstaben eingeben.");
    }
    int anzahl = numberOf(text, zeichen);

    println("-> " + anzahl);

}

static String toLowerCase(String text, int i) {
    String lowerText = "";
    if (i == text.length()) {
        return lowerText;
    } else if (text.charAt(i) < 'a') {
        return lowerText += (char) (text.charAt(i) - 'A' + 'a') + toLowerCase(text, i + 1);
    } else {
        return lowerText += text.charAt(i) + toLowerCase(text, i + 1);
    }
}

static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
    return hilfe(text, characterToCount, 0, 0);
}

static int hilfe(String t, char ch, int i, int a) {

    if (t.length() == a) {
        return i;
    } else if (t.charAt(a) == ch) {
        return hilfe(t, ch, i + 1, a + 1);
    } else {
        return hilfe(t, ch, i, a + 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you aren't reducing text when you call the method so the length is never reduced to 0.  Here is what you should be doing.  Note that you **do not need to pass an index** to the method.  Just keep reducing the text by 1 each time and just check the first character for equality to the target character.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(numberOf("ksjssjkksjssss", 's'));
}
    
    
static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (text.charAt(0) == characterToCount) {
        // call method and add 1 since you found a character
        return numberOf(text.substring(1), characterToCount) + 1;
    }
    // just call the method.
    return numberOf(text.substring(1), characterToCount);
    
}
```

The above prints

```
8
```

Ok, here is my modified version to meet your requirements of using only `String.length` and `String.charAt`.  The char is really 16 bits so I use the high order byte to store the current index.  I increment that index for each recursive call to maintain the current position of the search.  When I add `256` to the character I am really adding `1` to the high order byte.

```
static int numberOf(String text, char ch) {
    // stop when index exceeds text length
    if (ch >> 8 >= text.length()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (text.charAt((ch >> 8)) == (ch & 0xff)) {
        return numberOf(text, (char)(ch + 256)) + 1;
    }
    return numberOf(text, (char)(ch + 256));
}
```

This will not work as written on some character sets that are wider than 8 bits.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am not allowed to use .substring

Comment: Wow that is clever but obfuscated. If you pass along 2 seperate pieces of information (index and char), use 2 arguments. Besides being really hard to read, this code will cause wierd failures when the char is a non-ascii character or the string is longer than 255 characters. I would expect any bitshifting and masking on chars to be Unicode Voodoo.

Comment: @RasmusDamgaardNielsen Did you notice the constraints?  You must pass 1) only text and the character to count, and 2) may not use other methods than `String.charAt()` and `String.length()`

Comment: Well this works, but I don't fully understand why :D
I didn't learned in my lessons yet what >> means for example

Comment: Thats a right shift for the bits  Here are some explanations https://stackoverflow.com/q/30004456/12181863

Answer (score 4):

WJS's answer looks good but if you want simpler solution, this might help as well.

The problem in your solution is that your update of `i` and `erg` in one call stack is not seen/used by the next recursive call stack, since they are local variables and every stack will have their own copy of i and erg. They are always initialized as 0 in every call of `numberOf` method.

If substring isn't allowed then one way would be to make use of an extra variable that holds the index of position in the text you are comparing.

But on doing so you'll probably have to modify the signature of your method (if you don't want to use a class level static variable). And since you've mentioned that your method has to have only two arguments (text, charToCount), one way to achieve this easily would be to make use of a helper method (containing extra `index` argument) and your method can call it.

```
static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
    return helper(text, characterToCount, 0);
}

static int helper(String text, char charToCount, int index) {
    if (text.isEmpty() || index == text.length()) return 0;

    int countCharOnRight = helper(text, charToCount, index+1);

    return (text.charAt(index) == charToCount) ? 1 + countCharOnRight : countCharOnRight;
}
```

Comment: This is really concise and helps me further understand recursions. Upvoted. (edit: I m guessing this is probably what the model answer for the homework would look like)

Comment: That includes another method which was not permitted based on the constraints.

Comment: @WJS My take on the constraints that are currently known to us via the body of the question is that the lecturer (?) doesnt want the students to use any in-built shortcuts and have the students do things manually (ie no substring() and manually access via charAt() ). So unless we know explicitly what is not allowed, I would say this fits the current constraints very well.

Answer (score 1):

**What**

```
static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
    return numberOfRecursive(text, characterToCount, 0);
}

// Recursive helper function
static int numberOfRecursive(String text, char characterToCount, int index) {

    if (index == text.length()) // Abort recursion
        return 0;

    if (text.charAt(index) == characterToCount) // check char at index, then check next recursively
        return numberOfRecursive(text, characterToCount, index + 1) + 1;
    else
        return numberOfRecursive(text, characterToCount, index + 1);
}
```

**Why**

Most recursive problems require a helper function, that actually performs the recursive part. It will be called from the original function with initial values, here with our text, character and a starting position of 0.

Then, the recursive function needs an abort condition, which I provide by a bound check. We terminate if our recursion reached the end of the string.

Finally the recursive function does some calculation which it bases on a recursive call. Here we add 1 to our result, if the char at our index position is the one to count. If not, we continue counting without adding 1.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of recursion is that you call the same function/method a lot of times after some conditions. A good approach is to call the same function but reduce the string to check each time.

**Class**

```
public class StringUtils {
    
    public int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
       int count = 0;
       if (text.length() != 0) {
           if(text.charAt(0) == characterToCount) { //Only increment when is the same character
               count++; 
           }
           count = count + numberOf(text.substring(1, text.length()), characterToCount); //Do a substring but remove the first character
       }

       return count;
   }
}
```

**Test**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class StringUtilsTest {
    
    @Test
    public void should_count_all_the_ocurrences() {
        
        //Given
        StringUtils utils = new StringUtils();
        String sentence = "</www></palabraRandom></www></palabraRandom></palabraRandom></www>";
        
        //When
        int output = utils.numberOf(sentence, '>');
        
        //Then
        assertEquals(6, output);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that i am not allowed to use .substring :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use an index variable if it is reached to the end returns 0. Otherwise, return 1 if it is letter or 0.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(numberOf("Hello World-1234", 'o'));
    }

    private static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
        if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            return numberOf(text.substring(1), characterToCount) + (text.charAt(0) == characterToCount ? 1 : 0);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Implementation without `substring`

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(numberOf("Hello World-1234", 'o'));
    }

    private static int numberOf(String text, char characterToCount) {
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
        char[] newChars = new char[chars.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(chars, 1, newChars, 0, newChars.length);

        return numberOf(new String(newChars), characterToCount) + (chars[0] == characterToCount ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: But your program will always return 0...? It's not counting...

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, didn't see ```(text.charAt(index) == characterToCount ? 1 : 0);```  upvoted

Comment: I am not allowed to add smth :/

Comment: I didn't realize the constraint. I have updated the code

Comment: Is it possible without .substring?

Comment: I have posted another possible way.