# Nth root of BigInteger

Tags: java, math, biginteger, square-root

I'm using a BigInteger object. With normal ints or longs, I can use Math.pow(number, 1/nth root) to get the nth root. However, this will not work with a BigInteger. Is there a way I can do this?

I do not actually need the root, just to know if it is a perfect power.
I'm using this to figure out if the given BigInteger is a perfect square/cube/etc.

Comment: This might help: http://www.java-examples.com/find-square-root-biginteger-example

Comment: Relevant: Guava's [`BigIntegerMath.sqrt`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html#sqrt(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.RoundingMode))

Comment: Are you attempting to find the `n`th root because you need that value, or do you just need to know if it's a perfect power?

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407839/how-can-i-find-the-square-root-of-a-java-biginteger

Comment: Thanks Louis. Just what I needed for the sqrt part. I also need to determine if it is a cube too.

Comment: http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/icbrt.c.txt has algorithms for the integer cube root.  I'd just translate those to `BigInteger`.

Comment: Newton's method for nth roots is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newton's method works perfectly well with integers; here we compute the largest number *s* for which *s<sup>k</sup>* does not exceed *n*, assuming both *k* and *n* are positive:

```
function iroot(k, n)
    k1 := k - 1
    s := n + 1
    u := n
    while u < s
        s := u
        u := ((u * k1) + n // (u ** k1)) // k
    return s
```

For instance, `iroot(4, 624)` returns 4 and `iroot(4, 625)` returns 5. Then you can perform the exponentiation and check the result:

```
function perfectPower(k, n)
    return (k ** iroot(k, n)) == n
```

For instance, `perfectPower(2, 625)` and `perfectPower(4, 625)` are both true, but `perfectPower(3, 625)` is false.

I'll leave it to you to translate to Java BigInteger.

Comment: Hmm. I've translated this, but it doesn't seem to work. iroot always just returns n

Comment: I used the algorithm stated at the top and got it. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, the implementation here makes no sense. it will always go through the loop exactly once.

Comment: @JamesMcDowell: `this […] doesn't seem to work` & `I used the algorithm stated at the top` what *is* that algorithm/top?

Comment: For future transcribers, there's two major things you should know about this.
**1)** `k` is the nth root looking for num^(1/k), and `n` is the num. This is opposite of what people think of when doing things similar to this, like how Math.pow is (num, exp)
**2)** The `//` means floored division, not comments. If translating to JavaScript, I know that BigInt automatically does floored division.
If you want to see a Javascript version, [come to this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190185/how-do-i-extract-the-nth-root-of-a-bigint-in-javascript/64190462#64190462)

Answer (score 2):

For starters you can use **binary search** it is easy to implement let:

- `x` be your bigint
- `n` the n-th power you want to check

so you want to check if there is `y` such that `y^n=x` and for starters assume `x>=0` The algorithm is like this:

1. **first compute `y` limit `ymax`**

   I would use `2^(log2(x)/n)` which is the number with `(bits used for x)/n` so `ymax^n` has the same amount of bits as `x`. So first count the bits of `x` and then divide it by `n`

   ```
   for (ymax=1,i=1;i<=x;i<<=1) ymax++; ymax=(ymax/n);
   ```

   now `ymax` is the number of bits the `y` need to be tested up to
2. **bin search**

   ```
    for(m=1<<ymax,y=0;m;m>>=1)
     {
     y|=m;
     if (integer_pow(y,n)>x) y^=m;
     }
    return (integer_pow(y,n)==x);
   ```

   the `integer_pow(y,n)` can be done by binary powering or with single for loop for small `n`
3. **add handling the sign**

   if `(x<0)` then `n` must be odd obviously and `y<0` so if not return false else negate `x` and also the final `y` result.

**[edit1] Here some simple C++ example:**

```cpp
bool is_root(DWORD &y,DWORD x,DWORD n) // y=x^(1/n) return true if perfect nth root
    {
    DWORD i,p,m; y=x;
    if (n==0) { y=0; return (x==0); }
    if (n==1) { y=x; return (x!=0); }
    for (i=1,m=1;m<x;i++,m<<=1); m=1<<(i/n); // compute the y limit
    for (y=0;m;m>>=1) // bin search through y
        {
        y|=m;
        for (p=y,i=1;i<n;i++) p*=y; // p=y^n
        if (p>x) y^=m; // this is xor not power!!!
        }
    for (p=y,i=1;i<n;i++) p*=y; // p=y^n
    return (p==x);
    }
```

so just convert the `DWORD` to your bigint datatype as you can see you need only basic arithmetic and bit operations like `+,<,==,<<,>>,|,^` (the last is XOR not power)

There are also other possibilities to do this for some inspiration check this (and all sublinks in there):

- [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214)

So for example you can get even rid of the `*` operations (like I did in the 16T sqrt sublink presented in one of the sublinks (title: ... one cycle only)) Which is a huge speed up on bigints.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this function I got from Newton's formula

```
public boolean perfectPower(BigDecimal a, double n){
    BigDecimal[] x = new BigDecimal[40];
    x[0] = BigDecimal.ONE;
    int digits = a.toString().length();
    System.out.println(digits);
    int roundTo = digits + 1;
    for(int k = 1; k < 40; k++){
        x[k] = (x[k - 1]
                .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf((int)n - 1))
                .add(a
                        .divide(x[k - 1]
                        .pow((int)n - 1), new MathContext(roundTo, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN))))
                .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1/n));
    }
    String str = x[39].toString();
    return str.substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1, str.indexOf(".") + 6).equals("00000");
}
```

Comment: I dunno. You are looking for an exact answer, but it's not clear to me that this method can give you an exact answer. And the final test is that the first 5 digits after the decimal point are zero? I'm going to guess that it would be easy to construct an example for which this method will fail ... hmm, try the fourth root of 10^12 + 1 by this method.

Comment: You can address that concern by iterating until the difference between x[i] and x[i+1] is less than 0.5, and then testing whether floor(x[i+1]) or ceiling(x[i+1]) is a perfect power ... by raising it to the power N.

Answer (score 0):

Factor the number and look at how many distinct factors there are. If there are is only one, it is a perfect n'th power, where n is the multiplicity of the factor. There may be more efficient methods but this is guaranteed to work.

Comment: But factorization is extremly expensive, and downright impossible if the number is big enough, so it's not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a BigInteger version for the Kth Root of N.
I have also included a power function.

```
//      Input the N, Kth root. Returns N ^ 1/K

    public static BigInteger Ith_Root(BigInteger N, BigInteger K) {

        BigInteger K1 = K.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger S  = N.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        BigInteger U  = N;
        while (U.compareTo(S)==-1) {
            S = U;
            U = (U.multiply(K1).add(N.divide(pow(U,K1)))).divide(K);
        }
        String str=""+N+"^1/"+K+"="+S;System.out.println(str);
       return S;   
    } 
    
public static BigInteger pow(BigInteger base, BigInteger exponent) {
      BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
      while (exponent.signum() > 0) {
        if (exponent.testBit(0)) result = result.multiply(base);
        base = base.multiply(base);
        exponent = exponent.shiftRight(1);
      }
      return result;
    }
```