# Understanding underlying logic/maths for calculating BigInteger square root in Java

Tags: java, biginteger, square-root

I wanted to calculate the square root of BigInteger in Java. While investigating, I found this great link [How can I find the Square Root of a Java BigInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407839/how-can-i-find-the-square-root-of-a-java-biginteger), asked earlier on StackOverflow.

There are two great code snippets given to solve this. But the underlying logic or maths is missing.

This is the first one :

```
BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger n) {
  BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
  BigInteger b = new BigInteger(n.shiftRight(5).add(new BigInteger("8")).toString());
  while(b.compareTo(a) >= 0) {
    BigInteger mid = new BigInteger(a.add(b).shiftRight(1).toString());
    if(mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(n) > 0) b = mid.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    else a = mid.add(BigInteger.ONE);
  }
  return a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

taken from [here](http://faruk.akgul.org/blog/javas-missing-algorithm-biginteger-sqrt/).

This is the second one :

```
public static BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger x) {
    BigInteger div = BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(x.bitLength()/2);
    BigInteger div2 = div;
    // Loop until we hit the same value twice in a row, or wind
    // up alternating.
    for(;;) {
        BigInteger y = div.add(x.divide(div)).shiftRight(1);
        if (y.equals(div) || y.equals(div2))
            return y;
        div2 = div;
        div = y;
    }
}
```

answered by @EdwardFalk.

Can anyone please explain or point to the underlying maths or logic, for the completeness of the topic.

Comment: [Newton's iteration rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsIteration.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are basically a [newton iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

However the first code snippet has some strange twists, so I would go for the second snippet.

Comment: Thanks I understood the iteration rule and the second code seems more obvious. But I don't understand what the line `BigInteger div = BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(x.bitLength()/2);` is doing? Is it setting `div=1`?

Comment: It creates a starting point for the iteration that is near the square root, i.e. a number halve the length of `x` by setting a single bit at this position.

Comment: Half the length, literally or mathematically?

Comment: half the number of (binary) digits.