# Can someone explain me this function that finds the square root of an BigInteger in Java?

Tags: java, biginteger, square-root

So I need to sqrt a BigInteger in pre Java 9 and I found below function to do that. I do understand the code, but I don't really get why its there. So I guess I don't really get the math behind it. Like why is (n / 32 + 8) used. Why is mid calculated the way it is. etc.

```
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = n.shiftRight(5).add(BigInteger.valueOf(8));
    while (b.compareTo(a) >= 0) {
        BigInteger mid = a.add(b).shiftRight(1);
        if (mid.multiply(mid).compareTo(n) > 0) {
            b = mid.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        } else {
            a = mid.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
    return a.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `n/32+8`?

Comment: This looks much more efficient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407839/how-can-i-find-the-square-root-of-a-java-biginteger

Comment: @Adam Warning: at least the top voted answer returns wrong values for some small numbers. See comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) applied to finding the zero of the polynomial *x*<sup>2</sup> - *n* *= 0*. Why is (*n / 32 + 8*) used as a seed? I have no idea as it is a rather poor approximation. A much better approximation that is almost as cheap to compute is `n.shiftRight(n.bitLength()/2);`

Comment: You are correct, I didn't look closely enough at the code before answering, and I wasn't aware of the bisection method before my answer. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** [James Reinstate Monica Polk is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58757591/12334583), this is not the Babylonian Method but rather the Bisection method. I did not look at the code carefully enough before answering. Please see his answer as it is more accurate than mine.

This looks to be the [Babylonian Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) for approximating square roots. (n/32 + 8) is just used as a "seed", as providing a sane starting value can provide a better approximation in fewer iterations than just picking any number.

Comment: I disagree, it is *not* the Babylonian method. Rather it is the bisection method. The bisection method converges more slowly than the Babylonian method.